# getFormattedValue give wrongly formatted cell value

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to get value from a cell using `getFormattedValue`, in the cell it is showing as `22 5/8` and the value I'm getting from `getFormattedValue` is `23\ ?/8`

If I use `getCalculatedValue` I'm getting the value `22.64`

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Do you get the correct value if you use `getCell` instead of `getFormattedValue`?

Comment: @Dave - If I use `getValue()`, I'm getting `=D5/2.54` for `getCalculatedValue()` I'm getting  `22.64` and `getFormattedValue`  I'm getting `23\ ?/8`. I think `getCell()` is for getting the cell object to which we can apply the above methods to access it's value.